# Unable to echo out User data from Database - says "Property [id] does not exist"

Tags: php, laravel

I've been trying to get past this error for almost 2 days now. Needless to say, I'm still pretty new to Laravel. I'm using the Laravel's registration form (with some modifications) and I'm storing that User data in a table called "customusers" in my Database. That data includes their name/email/gender/description etc. And I'm trying to use a Resource Controller to basically print and edit that data. The problem I'm facing is, whenever I try to echo the data on my main page, it gives me the error "Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance" or email/name. But when I echo the data with Auth::user()->id, it works. And that's fine, it's do-able if I only wanted to echo data. But I also want to edit that data and I'm gonna have to use my Model for that. So following is my code:

**Display.blade.php:**

```
<div id="wrapper">

<div id="content">
  <div id="card">
    <div id="front">
      <div id="top-pic"></div>
    <div id="avatar"><span style="position: absolute;padding-top: 17px;margin-left: 34px;color:  #fff;font-size:  64px;" class="h5">
        {{ Auth::user()->name[0] }}
    </span></div>
      <div id="info-box">
        <div class="info">
          <h1>{{ Auth::user()->name }}</h1>
          <h2>{{ Auth::user()->message }}</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="social-bar">
        <a href="{{ Auth::user()->facebook }}" target="_blank">
          <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
        </a>
        <a href="{{ Auth::user()->twitter }}" target="_blank">
        <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
        </a>
        {{ link_to_route('display.edit','',[$customusers->id],['class'=>'fa fa-edit']) }}

      </div>
    </div>
```

**Edit.blade.php:**

```
{!! Form::model($customusers,array('route'=>['display.store',$customusers->id],'method'=>'PUT')) !!}
            <div class="form-group">
                    {!! Form::text('name',null,['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Name']) !!}
             </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                    {!! Form::email('email',null,['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Email']) !!}
            </div>
                <div class="form-group form-row">
                        <div class="col-5">
                                {!! Form::select('gender', ['Male' => 'Male', 'Female' => 'Female'], null, ['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Choose Gender']); !!}
                        </div>
                        <div class="col">
                                {!! Form::text('facebook',null,['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Facebook ID']) !!}
                        </div>
                        <div class="col">
                                {!! Form::text('twitter',null,['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Twitter Handle']) !!}
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                        {!! Form::textarea('message',null,['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Talk about yourself']) !!}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                        {!! Form::button('Create',['type'=>'submit','class'=>'btn btn-danger col-lg-12']) !!}
                </div>
                {!! Form::close() !!}
```

**ProfileController.php**:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\CustomUser;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;


class ProfileController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $customusers = CustomUser::all();
        return view ('display',compact('customusers'));
}

/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function create()
{
   //
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show($id)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function edit(CustomUser $customusers) 
{
    return view ('edit',compact('customusers'));
}

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(Request $request, CustomUser $customusers)
{
    $customusers->update($request->all());
    return redirect()->route('display.index');
}


/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function destroy($id)
{
    //
}
}
```

**CustomUser.php** (Model):

```
   <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class CustomUser extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $table = 'customusers';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name','username','email','gender','password','message','twitter','facebook',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

**Web.php** (Routes):

```
    Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::resource('/display','ProfileController');
```

So as you can see, I'm using compact in index() function to feed it all the user data in my database, and when I dd($customusers) - it does show me the data in array. But when I use {{ $customusers->name }} - it gives me an error saying "Property [name] does not exist on this collection instance". And thus, the same occurs whenever I try to use `link_to_route('display.edit','',[$customusers->id],'')` for redirecting the user to the Edit page. Please help me see what I'm doing wrong here. I previously made a CRUD app and I basically did the same things and it all worked perfectly. So I'm not understanding what the problem here is..

Comment: in display.blade file you are looping the $customusers,right?

Comment: @venom for that scenario You should use my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to loop customers data:

```
@foreach($customusers as $customer)
 {{ link_to_route('display.edit','',[$customer->id],['class'=>'fa fa-edit']) }}
@endforeach
```

Or you can edit the current logged in data.

```
{{ link_to_route('display.edit','',[Auth::user()->id],['class'=>'fa fa-edit']) }}
```

Comment: Using foreach prints the data of all users, like if I have 2 users Jack & Steve, and I want to print Jack's data only (who is logged in) - foreach will print Steve's data too. Is there any other way around it?

Answer (score 0):

`$customusers->all()` return a Collection (array of models)

`$customers = [ {}, {}, {}, {} ]`

So when you try to get the property `name` or any other it's `undefined`

You need to loop throw in the view:

```
@foreach($customusers as $customer)

// Here you have access to all Properties of each $customer

@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are passing all users ( collection of data ) to the view by compact.

you've to use foreach loop to access those data.

try loop through in view

```
@foreach($customusers as $customuser)
{{ link_to_route('display.edit','',[$customuser->id],['class'=>'fa fa-edit']) }}
@endforeach
```

it will work

Comment: I only want to pass the data of the user who is viewing the page i.e who is logged in - how do I do that? Since foreach will print data of all users in my database.

Comment: Then just get the data of current logged in user by using Auth::user()->id !

Try This: 

CustomUser::where('id', Auth::user()->id)->get()->first();

Answer (score 0):

As I see your display blade file. You want to edit that user who is Authenticate.`Auth`

So that point you need to use `FindOrFail()` method in your controller file:

```
 <?php

 namespace App\Http\Controllers;
 use Illuminate\Http\Request;
 use App\CustomUser;
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
 use Auth;

 class ProfileController extends Controller
 {

     public function index()
     {
          $id = Auth::user()->id;
          $customusers = CustomUser::FindOrFail($id);
          return view ('display',compact('customusers'));
     }
 }
```

And Use display.blade.php file like:

```
{{ link_to_route('display.edit','',[$customuser->id],['class'=>'fa fa-edit']) }}
```

Of if you want to return all the data then use below code:

```
@foreach($customusers as $customuser)
     @if($customuser->id == Auth::user()->id);
          {{ link_to_route('display.edit','',[$customuser->id],['class'=>'fa fa-edit']) }}
     @endif
@endforeach
```

The controller as it is:

```
public function index()
{
    $customusers = CustomUser::all();
    return view ('display',compact('customusers'));
}
```